# Center images inside divs with bootstrap only in mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/g4ypamvo/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When this is viewed on desktop there's no problem, it's like I want. But in mobile, each image are aligned to left. Check the jsfiddle and reduce the output width. I've tried `margin: 0 auto`in each `div` or ise the `center` class of bootstrap but I can't get it, I need to see the images centered at mobiles resolutions. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap `text-center` class:

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-center">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
           <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
           <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was some few seconds later than the first one, but it use only 1 bootstrap class.

Answer (score 1):

well you have to use image-responsive class which comes with bootstrap and then use margin 0 and auto

```
<div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
```

Updated [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g4ypamvo/2/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
         <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"  class="img-responsive" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding-top: 54px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, but I'll pick the other answer because it only use 1 bootstrap class, and no adding style.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;padding: 54px 0;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

just use style="text-align:center;" in parent node

Comment: Actually this could be the best one, but better to add class text-center only once in the 3rd div, instead adding style. Thanks